# z-index doesn't work in IE

Tags: css, position, z-index

IE version is 6.0, the code is like below:

```
<div style="background-color: #4A840F; width:300px; height: 200px; position: relative;">
  <div style="background-color: #ED4100; width:200px; height: 500px; position: absolute;z-index: 100;"></div>
</div>
<div style="background-color: red; width:300px; height: 200px; position: relative;"></div>
```

if i remove the position=relative on the third div, everything is ok, but i can not since i need it to fix another element. However if don't remove it the z-index doesn't work in IE. It works in FF and chrome.

Could someone give me some help to resolve it? thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try giving that third div `zoom:1`?

Comment: only "zoom:1"? i added and tried just now, no any effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
z-index: 1;
```

to the style of your first div.

In IE6, the offset parent's z-index will override all its children's z-index values.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="background-color: #000; width:300px; height: 200px; position: relative;">
  <div style="background-color: blue; width:200px; height: 500px; position: absolute;z-index: 100;"></div>
</div>
<div style="background-color: red; width:300px; height: 200px; position: relative;z-index: -1;"></div>
```

Should work. Out of curiosity, why are you supporting IE6?

Comment: @Brent-Friar Thank you very much. it works. but in my real code when i added z-index=-1, the third div is hidden.

Comment: @drlouie-louierd, z-index:1 no effect.

Comment: When you use -1, what is the 3rd div hidden under? sounds like you are going to have to mess with the z-index of the next div down as well.